# How to send some event update from http Handler to a WebSocket Handler

Tags: go, websocket

I'm very new to Go language and trying to wrap my head around channels. To clear my understanding I have watched video tutorials, read some books, but I'm still feeling confused when comes to practical coding and use of channels in web app coded in Go.

What I'm trying to do is to have 2 URLS:

1. The usual normal GET or POST URL which displays or gets value and
   process it. In the back-end does some processing and I wish that
   processing output to be sent out in a websocket update to the same
   URL, so that no window refresh/reload is required.
2. A Gorilla package based websockets URL.

Following is the so far test code I tried, which is still a stripped down version of the mess of code I made trying to make a solution:

```golang
//file main.go
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "log"
    "time"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)


func logging(f http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println(r.URL.Path)
        if r.URL.Path == `/ws` {
            log.Println("WebSocket is accessed from ws://localhost:8080/ws")
        }
        f(w, r)
    }
}

type hotcat int

func (c hotcat) ServeHTTP(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(res, "cat cat cat")

    //Some code here who's output I want to pass to websockets url ws://localhost:8080/ws
    n := timeConsumingWork(4)
    fmt.Println("Random Number Print from cat: ", n)
    //Example the value of n I need to pass to ws://localhost:8080/ws, how can I do it?

    // Some other example test code just giving some random output from hotcat http handler
    // Would like to pass it's output to ws://localhost:8080/ws to print in websocckets output in browser
    go func(){
        out := make(chan string)
        go func(){
            for i := 0; ; i++ {
                out <- `foo said something`
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(2e3)) * time.Millisecond)
            }
            //out <- `foo said something`
        }()
        printer(out)
    }()
}

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}

// Execute this in browser console to initiate websococket connection and to send ws.send() commands etc.
/*
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws")
ws.addEventListener("message", function(e) {console.log(e);});
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
}

ws.send("foo")
ws.send(JSON.stringify({username: "Sat"}))

ws.readyState
ws.CLOSED
ws.OPEN
ws.close()
*/
func ws(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    socket, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for {
        msgType, msg, err := socket.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(string(msg))
        if err = socket.WriteMessage(msgType, msg); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var c hotcat

    http.Handle("/cat", c)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", logging(ws))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}


func timeConsumingWork(n int) int {
    time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(rand.Intn(500)))
    return n + rand.Intn(1000)
}


func printer(in <-chan string) {
    //log.Println(<-in)
    go func() {
        for {
            log.Println(<-in)
        }
    }()
}
```

```sh
# command shell output
$ go run main.go 

Random Number Print from cat:  891
2019/03/11 14:15:32 foo said something
2019/03/11 14:15:33 /ws
2019/03/11 14:15:33 WebSocket is accessed from ws://localhost:8080/ws
foo
2019/03/11 14:15:34 foo said something
2019/03/11 14:15:34 foo said something
2019/03/11 14:15:34 foo said something
2019/03/11 14:15:36 foo said something
2019/03/11 14:15:36 foo said something
^Csignal: interrupt
$
```

[image: websocket command input from browser]

I want to display the random output string "2019/03/11 14:15:34 foo said something" like outputs in websocket output in browser.

I'd really appreciate some direction or help.

I think the comments in the code, terminal output, and browser screenshot for this question should clear what I'm trying to do, but if this question is still unclear, please let me know, I'll try expanding on it more.

Thanks & Regards,

Satinder

**Update 1:**

I read, tried the Mat Ryer example of chat application: https://github.com/matryer/goblueprints/tree/master/chapter1/chat

Here's may code copy: https://github.com/satindergrewal/golang-practice/tree/master/chat-examples/mychat02

From the example I understand that if I have a web socket handle I can have the messages channeled from that websocket http handle to other connected web clients. But I'm still confused how I can send a message from a non-websocket http handle to a websocket handle route/address.

I know I can not just use this code for `/`'s `ServeHTTP`:

```golang
// ServeHTTP handles the HTTP request.
func (t *templateHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t.once.Do(func() {
        t.templ = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates", t.filename)))
    })
    fmt.Println(r.Host)
    t.templ.Execute(w, r)
    var room *room
    socket, _ := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    client := &client{
        socket: socket,
        send:   make(chan []byte, messageBufferSize),
        room:   room,
    }
    room.join <- client
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(8e3)) * time.Millisecond)
            client.socket.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Hello from / ServeHTTP Handle"))
            //fmt.Println("Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!")
        }
    }()
}
```

It already gives me the following error:

```sh
localhost:8080
2019/03/25 11:19:18 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Upgrader).returnError (server.go:81)
2019/03/25 11:19:18 http: panic serving [::1]:52691: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 39 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00013e140)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1769 +0x139
panic(0x13a3e00, 0x172dc20)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
main.(*templateHandler).ServeHTTP(0xc00008ef60, 0x14954a0, 0xc0001dc380, 0xc000214200)
        /Users/satinder/go/src/golang-practice/chat-examples/mychat02/main.go:40 +0x209
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x173cfa0, 0x14954a0, 0xc0001dc380, 0xc000214200)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2375 +0x1d6
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000130000, 0x14954a0, 0xc0001dc380, 0xc000214200)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2774 +0xa8
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00013e140, 0x1495ba0, 0xc0000a0380)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1878 +0x851
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2884 +0x2f4
```

**Update 2:** Tried different, after re-reading the first reply from comments again.

```golang
// ServeHTTP handles the HTTP request.
func (t *templateHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t.once.Do(func() {
        t.templ = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates", t.filename)))
    })
    fmt.Println(r.Host)
    t.templ.Execute(w, r)

    room := newRoom()
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(8e3)) * time.Millisecond)
            room.forward <- []byte("Hello from / ServeHTTP Handle")
            //client.socket.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Hello from / ServeHTTP Handle"))
            fmt.Println("Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!")
        }
    }()
}
```

Now it doesn't give error, but I don't see the console showing the second client added which I was expecting that `/` added via command line.

```sh
GoldenBook:mychat02 satinder$ go build -o chat 
GoldenBook:mychat02 satinder$ ./chat 
2019/03/25 11:37:49 Starting web server on :8080
localhost:8080
New client joined
^C
```

Tried again with previous and new code mix and this is the result:

```golang
// ServeHTTP handles the HTTP request.
func (t *templateHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t.once.Do(func() {
        t.templ = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates", t.filename)))
    })
    fmt.Println(r.Host)
    t.templ.Execute(w, r)

    room := newRoom()
    socket, _ := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    client := &client{
        socket: socket,
        send:   make(chan []byte, messageBufferSize),
        room:   room,
    }
    room.join <- client
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(8e3)) * time.Millisecond)
            room.forward <- []byte("Hello from / ServeHTTP Handle")
            //client.socket.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Hello from / ServeHTTP Handle"))
            //fmt.Println("Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!")
        }
    }()
}
```

```sh
GoldenBook:mychat02 satinder$ go build -o chat 
GoldenBook:mychat02 satinder$ ./chat 
2019/03/25 11:40:44 Starting web server on :8080
localhost:8080
2019/03/25 11:40:50 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Upgrader).returnError (server.go:81)
^C
```

Still feeling confused...

Can someone please give me a solution to this? Would really really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Satinder

Comment: Thanks, will try to understand this example's code and use it to fix mine. will update question if stuck again.

Comment: came across this video, which also explains the same concept: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNxfgXrHeAg

I did not had thought of using own type struct as channel type. gonna play with that code. :-)

Comment: Hi @CeriseLimón, updated the question. Can you please help with it?

Comment: >The call to upgrader.Upgrader from that method fails because the connection is already in use for the HTTP response.
>

yes, so how I can send a socket message as I'm trying to do from `/` to `/room` ?

Comment: :( sad that I couldn't convey what I'm trying to do with the code examples. I have a code which uses a package webtty. I used it's code to run a console only application to run in a web page. With WebTTY, I'm quiting the WebTTY session and that prints a log output in console log, which I wish to broadcast to the websocket. This is my practice code I was trying to solve: bit.ly/2CGwQAh

Comment: So, in similar way I showed in this example in question, I just used the for loop to simulate that print log from some other Handle which I want to broadcast to the websocket, and still couldn't my head around how exactly I do it.
Really apprecicate your help so far mate. It at least encouraged me to read and learn more things around the concept where I'm still stuck.

Comment: thanks for replies Cerise. Yes, adding upgrade code to `/` doesn't make sense as you explained. Separating HTTP from WebSocket, makes sense. So, I looked at the gorilla docs and examples again. May be I should try to make a backend connection to websocket like a command line client connection, using `Dialer`, which also is coded in example `echo`. github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go#L32
Will try this code. Is that what you mean by separating?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Solved it mate! added my answer. Please take a look and let me know if I need to fix it due to some expected error or inefficiency. Many thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved it. At least it is doing what I imagined the code to do what I wanted it to do, even in case it might not be correct way of doing things. Correct way of doing things or efficient way of doing this exact thing, I think many of you can probably correct me and help me to do so, I hope so, so please comment and correct me if you think it's wrong or inefficient.

This is how I solved it:

I looked at the `echo` example (https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go) of gorilla's websocket examples, and just took the basic bit of code from `clients.go` file, which is makes a connection to websocket as a client.

My end goal was send the event update from another http Handle to the websocket, so for that I was simulating the print log example of some string in console output.

This is the change I did in the `main.go` file of my Mat Ryer chat example code:

```golang
// ServeHTTP handles the HTTP request.
func (t *templateHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t.once.Do(func() {
        t.templ = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates", t.filename)))
    })
    fmt.Println(r.Host)
    t.templ.Execute(w, r)

    // Creating the URL scheme to use with websocket Dialer
    // to connnect to ws://localhost:8080/room
    u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: "localhost:8080", Path: "/room"}
    log.Printf("connecting to %s", u.String())

    // Initiate the websocket connection from the go code **as a client** to connect to the chat room
    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(8e3)) * time.Millisecond)
            // Just printing the log of the same message in command line. Might better to ignore it.
            // log.Println("Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!")

            // Write the Message as Text message to the web socket connection
            // which will show up in the chat box
            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!"))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write:", err)
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

Running this code after building the binary prints the following example output in console:

```sh
GoldenBook:mychat02 satinder$ ./chat 
2019/03/31 03:44:27 Starting web server on :8080
localhost:8080
2019/03/31 03:44:31 connecting to ws://localhost:8080/room
New client joined
New client joined
2019/03/31 03:44:33 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
2019/03/31 03:44:36 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
2019/03/31 03:44:43 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
2019/03/31 03:44:45 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
2019/03/31 03:44:45 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
Message received: HELLO
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
2019/03/31 03:44:48 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
2019/03/31 03:44:48 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
2019/03/31 03:44:49 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
2019/03/31 03:44:52 Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
Message received: Sending automatic hello from root ServeHTTP handle to web page!
-- sent to client
-- sent to client
^C
```

And following is the output which shows in the web page at http://localhost:8080/

[image: chat window screenshot]

Here's the full code update:
https://github.com/satindergrewal/golang-practice/tree/master/chat-examples/mychat02

Since this is the example code, which I wanted to solve for my actual application, which is a WebTTY based app, I'll be able to send the WebTTY session end event update from some other http Handle to websocket using this code bit.

I can still use some help from go masters online.

Do I need to add the channel close to this Dialer somewhere? I guess I do, but would appreciate if someone can fix any errors or expected inefficiencies in it.

Thanks a lot to @cerise-limón who helped me so far. :-)